# How to make terminal background transparent and text background colors opaque?

Tags: macos, terminal

I've been using a terminal with a black background at 85% opacity for a while now, reading through git diffs fine. But I recently came across a way to add highlighting to the changes in lines in git diffs, so I would not only be able to see the added and removed lines, but also the changes that were made in those specific lines from within the terminal.

The inline changes show as black text with a red background for the removed text and black text with a green background for the added text, so basically the reverse of the unchanged text. All was going well until I ended up with a text editor behind my transparent terminal, and I realized that the colored backgrounds of the inline `git diff` changes were as transparent as the terminal background which made it progressively more difficult to read the `diff` the more the line I was reading happened to be lined up with a line of text in the text editor behind it.

Is there a way to specify that text background be opaque while still maintaining a transparent terminal? I'm on macOS High Sierra 10.13.6.